# Передача строки и файла через сокеты C#

Tags: c#, сокет

Имеется задача передачи через сокеты некоторой строки (которая несет инфу для sql-запроса) и файла. Все это должно передаваться одним массивом байт. Как разделить на приеме строку и файл? Как узнать, сколько байт занимает строка в общем массиве байт, который передается?

Answer (score 1):

Определяем структуру, где, допустим, первыми двумя байтами будет длина строки, например, следующими двумя имя файла (ну или что там от файла требуется) и потом уже на клиенте считываем согласно созданного нами же некоего подобия протокола передачи данных.

Comment: да структуру-то определил, как определить количество байт, которое занимает некоторая строка?

Comment: Посчитать и передать в своей структуре, либо кидать некий символ как признак завершения передачи строки.

Comment: Spawn, все, что Вы сказали, я и так все это понимаю. Мне нужен конкретный пример решения этой задачи, а не логические догадки.